# Initialization of pointer and how it is different from array?

Tags: arrays, pointers, initialization

Initialization of pointer and how it is different from array?
difference of (*p)[5]    &     *p[5] .

Comment: You need to specify a language.  C and C++ are much different from, say, Java.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider for integers.

`int *p[5]` means - `p` is an array of `5` pointers, pointing to integers.

`int (*p)[5]` means - `p` is a pointer which points to an array of `5` integers.